# IntelliJ IDEA Multiple type of terminals

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal

It is possible to configure multiple type of terminals in IntelliJ IDEA e.g. cmd, powershell, git bash, etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible at the moment, but there is a related feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-156939

Comment: Thanks for info.

Comment: Multiple terminal types / shells in IntelliJ Terminal have been implemented in IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2 (released July 27, 2021) - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68955432/68939) below / above.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ IDEA [2021.2](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/07/intellij-idea-2021-2/) (released July 27, 2021) introduces just [this feature](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-142610). While it is not explicitly mentioned in the [detailed Release Notes](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+2021.2+(212.4746.92+build)+Release+Notes) nor [documented](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/terminal-emulator.html) yet, IntelliJ now at start-up [scans a list of predefined shell locations](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/commit/f0734318c0cb065fd2af9eb00670b2f84015c942#diff-ea6e43155df63f322e2691a771c2aaba84483fb03235d0a32235c0e6fa7f2d3bR104) and, if it finds any, offers those via popup menu:

[image: Terminal Multi Shell Popup]

If you have your shells installed at non standard paths, eg. Git Bash at `D:\progs\Git\` instead of the default `C:\Program Files\Git\`, IntelliJ will not detect it. An easy workaround is to symlink the default to your custom location, eg. `mklink /j "C:\Program Files\Git" D:\progs\Git` [in an admin cmd.exe on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1020821/how-can-i-create-a-symbolic-link-on-windows-10/1020825#1020825).

Comment: That command would need quotes: mklink /j "C:\Program Files\Git" "D:\progs\Git"

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly - thanks for the hint!